# How can call python in snippet?

Tags: plugin-ultisnips, vimscript-python, snippets

I want to expand `ptest` into `welcome python` in file ending with html. Add these lines in `html.snippets`(located in vim-snippets/UltiSnips):

```
snippet ptest
!p print("welcome python")
endsnippet
```

and `ptest` expands into `!p print("welcome python")`. I then rewrite the snippet as below:

```
snippet ptest
`!p print("welcome python")`
endsnippet
```

but `ptest` expands into nothing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example provided in the question you could use

```
snippet ptest
welcome python
endsnippet
```

If instead, a more complex string to be constructed with python is desired, then use `snip.rv` (`.rv` stands for the "return value")

```
snippet ptest
`!p snip.rv="welcome python"`
endsnippet
```